# Java Web Start don't launch by JRE6 javaws.exe on installed JRE7 update 25

Tags: java, java-7, java-web-start, jnlp, java-6

**Environment:**

My Application is launched on ...

- Client

  - Windows 7 64bit
  - JRE 7 update 25 32bit
  - JRE 6 update 24 32bit
- Server

  - Redhat Linux 5
  - apache-tomcat-6.0.18
  - JDK 1.6.0 update 13 32bit

and

- I deploy JNLP to the Tomcat.
- This JNLP is set `<j2se version="1.6">`.
- Java Security is set lowest on selectable.

**Procedure until a problem:**

1. I pass Application URL to Javaws.exe. `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\javaws.exe" http://hoge.hoge/application`
2. Then Java Web Start Splashing Screen is displayed (Java6 screen).
3. After a moment, Splashing Screen is hide. But didn't launch my application.(And Javaws.exe process was stop. However Javaw.exe process was not stop.

I could not find error on the JWS log(javaws*****.log/.trace).

If that helps, My application was able to launch JRE6 javaws.exe on installed JRE7 update 21 (NOT installed update 25).

I want to launch by JRE6. Is there any solution? Please teach me. And I am sorry in poor English.

Comment: Read the release notes, http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u25-relnotes-1955741.html, is your application signed?

Comment: Thank you for commenting!

JAR was signed by myself-certificate.
(In addition, If JAR was not signed, I confirmed that JARSigningException)

 And I had added following parameters to all JAR's manifest file.

`Permissions: all-permissions`
`Codebase: *`

On the other hand, My App could launch when use JRE 7 update 25 Javaws.exe(NOT use JRE6. My App compiled on JDK 1.6.0 update 24. And JNLP is set `<j2se version="1.6+">`) 
 In other words I don't know the reason that My App don't launch by JRE6 because be able to launch by JRE 7 update 25.

Is the reason thought about elsewhere?